# How to programmatically stop Firefox from caching history

Tags: javascript

I am running a test in Firefox that requires me to open thousands of websites (one at a time) and close their tabs. I am having a weird memory leak issue that consumes all my virtual memory after a few hours and causes the test to crash. I am thinking that this may be occurring because Firefox stores in its history every site that was visited and other relevant information. When I close the test and reopen the browser, the history is cleared (but not while the test is running).

Is there any way I can use javascript to have Firefox stop storing the browser history?

Comment: ctrl + f5 refreshes with cache cleared for a given website. But you could just clear it in settings then open all the websites.

Comment: Just use [UnloadTab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/unloadtab/?src=api) I can open 1000 tabs without much increased memory.

Comment: Is there no way to do this using javascript? Such as by modifying about:config settings or something? And also - only one tab is open at a time. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does the test have to occur in Firefox?  Have you considered something like PhantomJS?

Comment: Could also be because you're opening thousands of websites in Firefox. History is nothing compared to the DOM.

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + Del lets you delete all history/cache/cookies/etc stuff without restarting the browser.